# Show div when right checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery, html, select, checkbox

I would like to check the value of a checkbox and compare this value with the class of multiple divs called: "entry". If the checkbox value is the same as the class of the "entry div" the entry div will be shown.

This my code:

```
<div class="entry float-left span4">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <div class="span3">
                            <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); ?>
                            <img class="art-circle" src=<?php echo $image[0]; ?> />
                        </div>
                        </a>
                        <div class="span8 entry-text">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1> 
                            </a>
                            <div class="art-date"><?php the_field('datum'); ?></div>   
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">         
                                <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                            </a>
                            <div class="art-location"><?php the_field('plaats'); ?></div> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

HTML checkbox

```
<ul class="submenu">
            <label class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" value="visueel">Visueel
            </label>
            <label class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" value="auditief">Auditief
            </label>
            <label class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" value="cognitief of neurologisch">Cognitief of neurologisch
            </label>
            <label class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" value="fysiek">Fysiek
            </label>
            <label class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" value="spraak">Spraak
            </label>
       </ul>
```

JQuery

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
        var checkboxname = $(this).val();
        $('.entry').each(function(i, obj) {
            var tags = $(this).find('.tags').html().toLowerCase();
            var arr = tags.split(',');
            $.each( arr, function( key, value ) {
              if(checkboxname==value){
                  alert(checkboxname+':'+value);
              }
            });
        });     
})
```

Instead of the alert I need to select the right entry div and say that it can be shown. I just don't know how to select this particular entry div. I can't use  $(this) because this refers to the checkbox and if I use .entry I will show all the divs with this class. What is the right solution?

Comment: fiddle please.....add your html code too..

Comment: where is the div code...be clear to get solved faster

Comment: your are using `<ul>` but where is the li tags

Comment: did you mean something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/sh2Lr/13/

Answer (score 1):

**FIDDLE:**

**http://jsfiddle.net/Hwwzv/1/**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="submenu">
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" value="visueel">Visueel
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" value="auditief">Auditief
    </label>
</div>

<div class="entry visueel">This is visual div</div>
<div class="entry auditief">This is auditief div</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.entry{
    display:none;
}
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function () {
    var checkboxname = $(this).val();
    if ($(".entry").hasClass(checkboxname)) {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $(".entry." + checkboxname).show();
        } else {
            $(".entry." + checkboxname).hide();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, using `hasClass` method

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
        var checkboxname = $(this).val();
    var checkedValue = $(this).is(':checked');
        // iterate all entry divs and show only matched div with checkbox value
        $('.entry').each(function() {

           if($(this).hasClass(checkboxname))
            {
               if(checkedValue)
                 $(this).show();
               else
                 $(this).hide();   
             }
         });
   });
```

This is the working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7SBPA/8/)

Comment: this refers to `input[type="checkbox"]` this is not the answer

Comment: but inside check box i am iterating entry div, so inside loop this refers to div and not check box

Comment: @susheel - please find updated answer and jsfiddle. sorry i have given one extra '})' so not working

Comment: yeah ...sure I will take care in future!!

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used this code to display all entries at first and then checcked which filters were selected to show all related entries:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function () {
    $('.entry').hide();
    $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function(){
        var textname = $(this).val();
        $('.'+textname).each(function(){
            $(this).show();
        });
    });
});
```

Thanks for the answers because it lead to the solution for my problem